# Мобильная версия сайта wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html5

Никак не могу понять, как отключить/убрать мобильную версию [сайта](http://case-iphone.by/).

Движок - *wordpress*. Все обыскал - ничего не нашел.

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Мобильная версия вашего сайта построена на CSS
`@media (max-width: 580px)`
Чтобы "отключить" мобильную версию, вам нужно отредактировать файл style.css вашей темы.